# How to use Jointjs and SVG to draw element tools

Tags: javascript, svg, jointjs

I'm new to javascript and SVG and I have no graphical programming background and this is my first project using all of those. So I started to make a custom element just like [Mike Goodwin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30275325/4438220) proposed and I ended with this code after editing it:

```
joint.shapes.tools.tooledElement = joint.shapes.basic.Generic.extend({

    toolMarkup: [
        '<g class="element-tools">',
            '<g class="element-tool-remove"><circle fill="red" r="11" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>',
                '<path transform="scale(.7) translate(-16, -16)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" d="M24.778,21.419 19.276,15.917 24.777,10.415 21.949,7.585 16.447,13.087 10.945,7.585 8.117,10.415 13.618,15.917 8.116,21.419 10.946,24.248 16.447,18.746 21.948,24.248z"/>',
                '<title>Remove this element from the model</title>',
            '</g>',
            '<g class="element-tool-link"><circle fill="green" r="11" cx="160" cy="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>',
                '<path transform="scale(.7) translate(-16, -16)"/>',
                '<title>creates a new link</title>',
            '</g>',
        '</g>'
    ].join(''),

    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
        attrs: {
            text: { 'font-weight': 400, 'font-size': 'small', fill: 'black', 'text-anchor': 'middle', 'ref-x': .5, 'ref-y': .5, 'y-alignment': 'middle' }
        }
    }, joint.shapes.basic.Generic.prototype.defaults)

});
```

Which works properly. Now I would like to draw some line on the green circle and to make the red circle into a red square. To achieve this I looked at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) tutorial on paths to draw and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Shapes) tutorial on basic shapes. But if I try to make a line on the green circle like this:

```
'<path transform="scale(.7) translate(-16, -16)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" d="x y L 10 10 " />'
```

it won't draw anything. They do say " If your cursor already was somewhere on the page, no line is drawn to connect the two places." and that's why I omitted the "M" from path.

So here comes the first question: **How can I draw the line on the center of the green circle without starting from the previous last point defined on any other path?**

To make the red square I tried the exactly example from the second tutorial changing the fill (as a test):

```
//first line to test
<rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="5"/>
```

or

```
//second line to test
<rect x="60" y="10" rx="10" ry="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="5"/>
```

The result of the first line would be the element at which the tools are being used to be draw again above itself like this:

[image: First line test]

And the second line would end up on nothing being show.

So here are the next questions:

**Why did the results from the first line got like that?**
and
**How can I change the red circle into any other shape?**

**UPDATE:**
About the line draw:

```
'<path transform="scale(.7) translate(-16, -16)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" d="M150 150 H 5 V 5 H 5 z" />'
```

If I use this code for example, this is the result:

[image]

```
'<path transform="scale(.7) translate(-16, -16)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" d="M150 150 H 5 V 5 H 5 z" />'
```

If I use this other code then the result will be:

[image]

The tutorial led me to believe that `M` is defining the start point but changing the `translate(-16, -16)` to something else made the correct start point be possible. So its the translate attribute combined with M that set the starting point.

Comment: Paths must begin with M (or m). Your x and y seem to be literal string values rather than variables, that won't work either.

Comment: x and y are actually numbers on my code. They are not literal string, I just forgot to make it clear that for any value to x and y it would not work. if I add M or m the draw will begin at the end of the previous draw as I stated before. For example on the picture above, it would start at the end of the white "X" on top left and be draw to the green circle as if it was a piece of the second draw.

Comment: Well you could set the M to whatever you want. It won't begin at the previous draw it will begin wherever you set the M start point.

Comment: I just found out why that wasn't working. It seems M is not the start point. I will update the question.

Comment: I couldn't be more wrong. M and translate defines the starting point. Another update required.

Comment: M is the start point. translate defines the co-ordinate system in which the M (and other) values are interpreted. Think of graph paper, translate moves or rotates the graph paper itself, M specifies a position on that graph paper. It's always the same position on the graph paper but it looks different because you've moved the graph paper about.

Comment: Yes. Do you have any idea as why the red circle can't become a red square?

Comment: It would help if you used jsfiddle to demonstrate what is happening. You could just edit the fiddle that I did in the answer that you reference to help you get started...

Comment: That was a good idea Mike! So here it is: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pfeiffer/mgfqh374/). I changed only the <circle fill="red" r="11"/> to <rect fill="red" width="30" height="30" x="10" y="10"/> so why does the tool rect keep the actor rect configuration? How can I change this so the red circle becomes a red square inside the rect actor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question as been answered on update. As for the second question (concerning the red square conflicting with the element shape inside a rect) this was my work around:

Use the path to draw the tools elements instead of using basic shapes, that way it won't conflict with the element shape.

Example:

```
'<g class="element-tool-link"><circle fill="green" r="11" cx="160" cy="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>',
    '<path transform="scale(.7) translate(-16, -16)"/>',
    '<title>creates a new link</title>',
'</g>'
```

would turn into:

```
'<g class="element-tool-link">',
    '<path d="M33 0 a 11 11 0 1 0 0.0001 0z " stroke="black" fill="lightblue" stroke-width="1"/>',
    '<path transform="scale(.7) " stroke="black" stroke-width="1" d="M58,16  H 37 "/>',
    '<title>creates a new link</title>',
'</g>'
```

where `'<path d="M33 0 a 11 11 0 1 0 0.0001 0z " stroke="black" fill="lightblue" stroke-width="1"/>'` defines a circle shape.